# CreateView with additional model

Tags: django, django-generic-views

I'm using a CreateView to create a User.

views.py:

```
class UserCreateView(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UserCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('patient:users')
```

forms.py

```
class UserCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']
```

I have another model, UserGroups, defined as follows:

```
class UserGroup(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='user_groups')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

The problem is that I would like to have the possibility to assign UserGroups to the User in the UserCreateForm. Doing this:

```
class UserCreateForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'user_groups']
```

does not seem to work.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to assign multiple `user_groups` to an user? @Micheal

Comment: Yes exactly! Using a multiple select

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to add an extra field to your UserCreateForm:

```
class UserCreateForm(ModelForm):
    groups = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=UserGroup.objects.all())
```

and set it in your CreateView's `form_valid` method:

```
def form_valid(self):
    response = super(UserCreateView, self).form_valid()
    self.object.user_groups = self.form.cleaned_data['groups']
    return response
```